# How to Upload an image in the form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form to add a contact, in that form I want to upload the image of the Contact with its other information like name, address, company name etc. So how can I add that image and store the image information to the database. Here is my html form and according to this what will be the Controller..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "saveContact", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="rowElem noborder">
                <label>
                    First name :</label><div class="formRight"><input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value ="@Model.FirstName" style="width: 600px; height:25px;font-size: 16px;" /></div>
                <div class="fix">
                </div>
</div>
<div class="rowElem">
                <label>
                    Upload Image :</label><div class="formRight"><input type="file" id="imageUpload" name="imageUpload" /></div>
                <div class="fix">
                </div>
            </div>
<input type="submit" id="btnAddContact" value="Save" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You could start by definig a view model that will mimic the input fields of your form:

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("First name :")]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Upload Image :")]
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action take this view model as argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(ContactViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Of course depending on the data access technology that you are using there might be different ways to save the contact to the database. For example if you are using plain ADO.NET you could have a method that does the save:

```
public int SaveContact(string firstName, byte[] photo)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING COMES HERE"))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Contacts (FirstName, Photo) VALUES (@firstName, @photo)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@photo", SqlDbType.BigInt, 20).Value = photo;
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

and then inside your controller action you could invoke this method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(ContactViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        model.ImageUpload.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
        byte[] photo = stream.ToArray();
        SaveContact(model.FirstName, photo);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Also I would recommend you using HTML helpers in your view to generate the input fields instead of hardcoding them:

```
@model ContactViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "saveContact", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="rowElem noborder">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName)
        <div class="formRight">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { style = "width: 600px; height:25px;font-size: 16px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName)
        </div>
       <div class="fix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowElem">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.UploadImage)
        <div class="formRight">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ImageUpload, new { type = "file" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ImageUpload)
        </div>
        <div class="fix"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="btnAddContact" value="Save" />    
}
```

---

UPDATE:

If you don't want to follow my advice about using view models and have passed directly your domain models to the view and you do not have an ImageUpload property in it and you cannot modify it you could still have the following controller action signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Contact model, HttpPostedFileBase imageUpload)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am using the view model named Contact and in that I haven't define the HttpPostedFileBase property and now I can't change it, So is there any way to do this..

Comment: Actually there is a way, take a look at my updated answer at the end. Personally I would recommend you using view models.

Comment: I have tried this earlier but after adding the image and submitting the form, this HttpPostedFileBase returns the null value..

Comment: The name of the parameter must exactly match the name of your file input tag. So if you have `<input type="file" id="imageUpload" name="imageUpload" />` then your action parameter must be called `imageUpload`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I've used the second option, how to use it while editing the record, i mean how to load image in modal from DB while editing the record.

Comment: @ITppl, you could have a controller action that will retrieve the image from the database and write it to the response stream by returning a FileResult. Then all you need to do in the modal is use an `<img>` and point its `src` attribute to this controller action.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Sir actually i am doing the same as suggested by you, but problem is that when i am saving the edited record i didn't get the image in postback request, i've to use it @ other place. How can i set it in HttpPostedFileBase ?

Comment: You have to store the image in your backend if you need to use it in other places. Otherwise you will lose it. The image will be available only to the controller action to which the file is being uploaded.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov but if I use first option from the answer, will it keep the images in model while it is postback from edit?

Comment: No, of course that it will not keep the image. The whole point of my first example is how to save the image in the database so that you could retrieve it later if you need it.